# How to achieve exceptional cognitive talent across multiple subjects to ace SAT College Admission Exam in > 12 months

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

***Scenario***: An individual has to ace a College Admission Exam in > 12 months. Subjects included in this admission exam are Maths,Physics and Chemistry.

***Inhibitor*** : This individual has very little knowledge of subjects like Maths,Physics and Chemistry

How can any arbitrary(able bodied) adult human with no major talent in subjects like Maths, Physics, Chemistry etc be able to develop exceptional cognitive talent(great problem solving skills)in those subjects within a period of 12 months or less?

In this context "*exceptional cognitive talent*" will mean something like- not understanding algebra to publishing influential papers in respected mathematics journals

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding. Please take a look at the [tour] and at the [help] center. The way your question is asked it will most likely be closed as being off topic.

Comment: Only one discipline is required ! He must play the game of go ! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29

Comment: @NeilSlater: Thank You! I have edited the question to remove any vagueness and make it more relevant. If you think more fine tuning is necessary then do let me know.

Comment: @Burki: Thanks. I have edited the question. I hope it is okay now. If not plz let me know.

Comment: @NeilSlater: By "any" I meant any arbitrary(able bodied) individual.

Comment: I think that this isn't really a worldbuilding question, given that it seems to be asking for a real world solution to a problem (how do I learn fast). If it is a worldbuilding question then it's idea generation, as the answers could be pretty much anything. If you can constrain it to a particular setting it might help narrow down the options, define the problem more and also provide a 'worldbuildy' slant to the question.

Comment: You are selling your child short if you think they have no talents. If your child has suddenly discovered an interest in science, that might be enough to motivate them to study very hard for hours every day. If it's you intervening because you think there is no money in liberal arts, good luck.

Comment: *Flowers for Algenon* and *Limitless* come to mind. I've also seen a short-lived tv show where a guy can have knowledge and skills uploaded to his brain, with a strict time limit for how long it sticks.

Comment: The SAT doesn't cover chemistry or physics ... it is critical reading mathematics and writing.  There are SAT II subject tests that cover specific subjects is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @sdrawkcabdear: Any college admission exam where the candidate's knowledge of Maths, Physics and Chemistry will be tested.I have edited the question.

Comment: I don't see this as a worldbuilding question, and at best it is Idea Generation.

Comment: @bowlturner: The Help Center says questions related to - `How to achieve a specified effect in a defined world, including by the use of technology or magic, while maintaning in-universe consistency` can be asked. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CSinha questions like that would be how would studding for college exams be changed if Vulcan style mind-melds where possible, or how would wizard college exams be structured.  State a different world or a hypothetical question.  Questions that can be looked up should be looked up.  SAT help books will give you tons of info for this question in our would.

Answer (score 3):

NB: This answers an earlier framing of the question which did not mention the lower level target of getting good college entrance exam results (which although a good thing for the entrant, is not really an indication of "exceptional" talent IMO):

> How can any arbitrary(able bodied) adult human with no major talent in
>   subjects like Maths, Physics, Chemistry etc be able to develop
>   exceptional cognitive talent(great problem solving skills)in those
>   subjects within a period of 12 months or less?
>
> In this context "exceptional cognitive talent" will mean something
>   like- not understanding algebra to publishing influential papers in
>   respected mathematics journals

---

**It is likely not possible.** There is no well-understood or known way to achieve so much progress in that time frame, even when considering a talented, highly motivated individual studying a single subject.

In the study of how humans acquire knowledge and skills, it is still a matter of debate how much depends on natural talent and how much on process and practice. Studying the subject of how talented people develop has ethical limits in that you can generally only look at successes and failures after the fact and try to rationalise. Planned and measured interventions (i.e. ones that follow scientific method and are not just best guesses and/or quackery) are usually only made at level of teaching basic skills in a school, they are not used in deliberate attempts to create exceptional scholars.

[Malcolm Gladwell claimed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outliers_(book)), based on studying successful experts, that 10,000 hours of sustained and hard practice can make an expert in many fields. If you accept this for mathematics, then a typical time frame from having only passing knowledge to being a world-class expert would be 10 years - approaches to achieving that much practice [are discussed in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EBZj_gxF9Q).

The book gained wide publicity, and its central message turned into a soundbite for media consumption. As a result there is much published about it, both for and against.

In addition there have been some studies that refute the central claim, such as [this study at Princeton](http://pss.sagepub.com/content/early/2014/06/30/0956797614535810.abstract). This refutation does not completely remove the claim that it takes a lot of time and effort to reach the edges of human ability in any field, but it does remove the simplicity of "just put in 10,000 hours practice". It is in part the old [nature vs nurture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nature_versus_nurture) debate. So from the point of view of the original question, this is a bad thing - you probably cannot just take anyone willing to try hard and get top results. However, you may still get results that are useful, such as showing that even someone struggling at school can improve dramatically with the right attitude and training - see e.g. [Jamie's dream school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie%27s_Dream_School).

So we are left with one proposed, and partially flawed way to achieve what you are asking - lots of hard work learning and practicing - but that would take longer than you suggest. And no real alternatives, no fast track that could work for anyone - at least nothing with measured scientific support.

Comment: Just a question: aren't there 5700 waking hours in a year? Maybe more if you don't need a "standard" 8 hour sleep? Then, 10,000 hours is less than two years...
Of course, I realize one has to eat, shower, attend rock concerts... But 3 years seems enough to plug 10,000 on-topic hours in?

Comment: @DraxDomax: I don't know, but I suspect that there are caveats and limits explained in the research. Most people would burn out quite quickly attempting 12 hours/day training on something they found hard. There is going to be a cutoff of maximum learning rate before diminishing returns well below total waking hours, unless your natural talent is for extreme endurance and enthusiasm. More like 3-4 hours per day on average, but I guess it will depend on the subject matter.

Comment: @Absolutely agree. If anything, I made actual learning while NOT studying the material. I need rest to let it sink in and I need to be occupied with something else to give my brain a perspective on that main thing...
Our brains are weird (well, at least mine!)